# displaying sequence of numbers

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand the pattern of these sequence of numbers and write c++ code using one of loop structures.the numbers are:
1, 2, 5, 14, 41, ...

I want the code to display these numbers.Can somebody help me with this?Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not a programming question as far as I see.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for such sequences on your favorite web search engine and you'll usually end up on OEIS.org.  In this case, here: https://oeis.org/A007051

Your equation is `(3^n + 1)/2`.